# Which physical directory is the firefox's localstorage directory?

Tags: html, firefox, local-storage

There are three browsers installed on my local pc :firefox,chrome,opera.

```
find /  -name  'Local Storage'
/home/debian8/.config/opera/Local Storage
/home/debian8/.config/google-chrome/Default/Local Storage
```

The physical directory to store data on them can be found with `find /  -name  'Local Storage'` for opera and chrome ,not for firefox.
Which physical directory is the firefox's localstorage directory?

```
ls /home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/4qfwwwo5.default/storage
default  permanent  temporary
```

In order to  trace out the physical directory,an array was stored in local storage in firefox this way.
1.to open https;//www.yahoo.com in firefox
2.to store the array with js in firebug--console

```
var arrDisplay = [0, 1, 1, 1];
localStorage.setItem("menuTitle", arrDisplay);
```

[image]
    ls /home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/4qfwwwo5.default/storage
    default  permanent  temporary

It is most likely in the default directory.

```
ls /home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/4qfwwwo5.default/storage/default
https+++www.yahoo.com
ls /home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/4qfwwwo5.default/storage/default/https+++www.yahoo.com
idb
ls /home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/4qfwwwo5.default/storage/default/https+++www.yahoo.com/idb
301792106ttes.files   301792106ttes.sqlite-shm
301792106ttes.sqlite  301792106ttes.sqlite-wal
sqlite3  /home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/4qfwwwo5.default/storage/default/https+++www.yahoo.com/idb/301792106ttes.sqlite-shm
SQLite version 3.8.7.1 2014-10-29 13:59:56
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .table
sqlite> .exit
sqlite3  /home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/4qfwwwo5.default/storage/default/https+++www.yahoo.com/idb/301792106ttes.sqlite-wal
SQLite version 3.8.7.1 2014-10-29 13:59:56
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .table
sqlite> .exit
sqlite3  /home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/4qfwwwo5.default/storage/default/https+++www.yahoo.com/idb/301792106ttes.sqlite
SQLite version 3.8.7.1 2014-10-29 13:59:56
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .table
database            index_data          object_store        unique_index_data
```

file                object_data         object_store_index
    sqlite> select * from database;
    test|https://www.yahoo.com|1|1473647521683690|0|49152
    sqlite> select * from index_data;
    sqlite> select * from object_store;
    sqlite> select * from unique_index_data;
    sqlite> select * from file;
    sqlite> select * from object_data;
    sqlite> select * from object_store_index;

No clue about the `menuTitle`.

```
ls /home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/4qfwwwo5.default/storage/permanent
chrome  indexeddb+++fx-devtools  moz-safe-about+home
```

It is most likely the indexeddb+++fx-devtools  directory.

```
ls /home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/4qfwwwo5.default/storage/permanent/indexeddb+++fx-devtools
idb
ls /home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/4qfwwwo5.default/storage/permanent/indexeddb+++fx-devtools/idb
478967115deegvatroootlss--cans.files  478967115deegvatroootlss--cans.sqlite
sqlite3  /home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/4qfwwwo5.default/storage/permanent/indexeddb+++fx-devtools/idb/478967115deegvatroootlss--cans.sqlite
SQLite version 3.8.7.1 2014-10-29 13:59:56
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .table
database            index_data          object_store          unique_index_data  file     object_data         object_store_index
sqlite> select * from database;
devtools-async-storage|indexeddb://fx-devtools|1|1475141158242996|0|49152
sqlite> select * from  object_store;
1|0|keyvaluepairs|
```

Where the `menuTitle` was stored in firefox's installed directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In modern Firefox, `localStorage` data is stored in [webappsstore.sqlite<sup>Doc</sup>](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Webappsstore.sqlite), which you can find in your [profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder).
In your case it looks like you want:

```
/home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/4qfwwwo5.default/webappsstore.sqlite
```

---

The `/storage/default/...` folders are for [Indexed DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_Database_API) files -- which is a different beastie than localStorage.